# Ужели - неужели

Tags: словообразование, семантика

Частица *неужели* означает сомнение, недоверие, удивление. В старых текстах встречается также слово *ужели*, ныне устаревшее.

Теоретически, приставка не- должна придавать слову противоположное значение. Но ведь слова *ужели* и *неужели* означают одно и то же, не так ли?
Почему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Частица НЕ имеет значение не только отрицания, но и

А) утвердительности при употреблении двойного отрицания: нельзя не сознаться (то есть «надо сознаться»).

Б) усиления утвердительного смысла в  вопросительных и восклицательных предложениях: как не, кто не, кто только не, где не,; сюда примыкают вопросительные предложения с сочетанием не - ли, например:
Ну, как не порадеть родному человеку! (Грибоедов).Чем ты не молодец? (Пушкин).  Чем не работа! Не ты ли это был?

В)  предел, до которого длится действие (в соединении с союзом пока )в придаточном предложении, например: Сиди тут, пока не приду.

Г) усиление отрицания: далеко не, отнюдь не, ничуть не, нисколько не, вовсе не,

Неужели =  не + уже́+ ли - употребляется при вопросе, для выражении сомнения, удивления, т.е. интонация вопросительная(или восклицательная), как в предложении: Да не изволишь ли сенца? (Крылов). Здесь явно функция усиления утвердительного смысла. Так что всё по правилам.

Answer (score 0):

Не лезет у меня в комменталий к Людмиле....

> Неужели = не + уже́+ ли - употребляется при вопросе, для
> выражении сомнения, удивления, т.е. интонация вопросительная(или восклицательная), как в предложении: Да не изволишь ли сенца? (Крылов). Здесь явно функция усиления
> утвердительного смысла. Так что всё по правилам.

Да. Все, разумеется, по правилам. И это конечно, не отрицание, по крайней мере - в классическом понимании.
Сомнения в том, усилительная ли тут (в последнем примере) функция. Скорее всего - форма вежливости, в некотором смысле даже - ослабление.

Но это не главное. Можно ли из такого примера выводить значение "неужели" - или хотя бы проводить аналогию? Не думаю.

Тут, имхо, несколько другой смысл.
**Ужели**, если я не ошибаюсь, выводится из **уже+ли**, а уже - в свою очередь из "**у+же**" где "ли" и "же" - частицы в обычном для современном языка значении, а "у" - это исходная форма для нынешнего "уже", наречие со смыcлом существования, реальности, бытия; это значение сохранилась в современной глагольной приставке "у" придающей значение результативности дейcтвия: убить, украсть, уверовать. Т.е. "уже ли" - выражало сомнение в *реальности* (почти как  "уже ли" в современном языке: "[сделано] ли это уже?" ), а "не уже ли" - обратное, т.е. сомнение в *нереальности*. В каком-то смысле, сомнение в нереальности можно считать и "усилением" сомнения в реальности, но это уже как посмотреть, "философия, однако". 
"Голодны ли Вы?" - "Не голодны ли Вы?" Если что и усиливает, то только сомнения.

*"Я сомневаюсь, поручик, была ли у вас мать"* ("Адъютант его превосходительства").  
*"Я сомневаюсь, поручик, не была ли у вас мать"* - А тут что чего усиливает?!

История напомнила разбиравшийся тут пример. "Чайник долго закипает" и "Чайник долго не закипает" означает одно и то же. Хотя это никак не усиление.

Comment: Это Вы полезли вглубь.В лингвистике есть понятие отрицательного/положительного высказывания, а сомнение - часть положительного, оттенок.Отсюда усиление утверждения/усиление отрицания. Ваша "сомнительность" входит  в вопрос.Предложение вопросительное - уже сомнение, но по большому счёту при выведении правила о применении НЕ-НИ это не главное.Авторы учли это в примечании: сюда примыкают вопросительные предложения с сочетанием не - ли, например:  Не ты ли это был?Этого достаточно.Иначе было бы усиление всехмодальных значений К чему загромождать правила?

Comment: Людмила, а в чем я неправ-то конкретно?  
Вопросы терминологии меня не очень интересуют, Вы знаете. Ну употребил я слово "усиление" не совсем в том значении, на котором Вы настаиваете, смысл-то от того не изменился, пониманию не мешает. А что ещё-то? Разве исторический морфоанализ неверен?   

Ни о каких "правилах" я даже не заикался. Тем более не "загромождал". Если Вы о принципе бритвы Оккама ("не плоди сущности"), то он тут не работает, Ваше "простое" объяснение нисего на самом деле не объясняет, а только показывает

Comment: что такое положительное высказывание, а от того, что Вы не указали, что собственно, усиливает якобы усилительная здесь частица, ставшая в современном написании приставкой (ну или как там ее тракотвать)

Ни о каких "правилах" я даже не заикался. Если Вы о принципе бритвы Оккама ("не плоди сущности"), то он тут не работает, Ваше "простое" объяснение ничего на самом деле не объясняет в конкретной, а только демонстрирует возможность такой, что "не" - усилительная. Я с тем не спорю.

ЗЫ С праздником! Всеческих успехов и радости везде и во всем.