# Неужели не у ли

Tags: этимология

Не могу понять как старославянское "не у ли" в значении "ещё не" + частица "ли" прибавляемая в вопросительных предложениях могло превратиться в русское неужели в значении "разве"?

что есть Мне и тебе жено; **не у** прииде часъ Мой.

**не уже** бо бе пришелъ Иисус въ весь, но бе на месте идеже срете Его Марфа.

**не у ли** разумеваете, яко всяко еже въходитъ въ уста, въ чрево вмещается, и афедрономъ исходит?

Comment: Начало цитат унижены, но Его-то — нельзя, да и Марфу-то за что со строчной? Мне и Мой — тоже о Нём.

Comment: это "посимвольная" цитата, в старославянском заглавные для имён и местоимений не использовались,  в противном случае это перестанет быть цитатой

Comment: Вы же не старый славянин, или старый?

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/17065/Ужели-неужели

Answer (score 2):

А что смущает?  **У** -церковная временн**а**я наречная частица; **не у** - **не уже**, **нет еще**, **еще не**. "Не у прииде час мой" - "ещё не пришёл час мой" Иоан.

Сначала срослись (или наложились одна на другую) две частицы - у (уже, теперь) + же:

> УЖЕ. Общеслав. Сложение частиц у < *ju «уже» (ср. церковно-слав. ю
>   «уже, теперь») и же.

https://shansky.lexicography.online/%D1%83/%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5

Потом добавилась вопросительная частица ли (https://lexicography.online/etymology/%D0%BB/%D0%BB%D0%B8)
Получилось **ужели** - вопросительное слово.

При отрицании у вопросительного слова появилось значение сомнения, удивление: **неужели?..**

https://lexicography.online/etymology/%D0%BD/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8