# Приставка у уже

Tags: этимология

Не являлось ли русское слово уже (ст.слав. у) ранее отделяемой глагольной приставкой?

Например:

не у ли разумеваете, яко всяко еже въходитъ въ уста, въ чрево вмещается, и афедрономъ исходит?

То есть:

не уразумеваете ли,...

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/17065/Ужели-неужели